# How to handle twig view and bootstrap 3 rows/columns?

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3, twig

I have an Article entity and I made a **findAll()** in the controller.

I rendered each article in a div with the **col-md-6** class.

But foreach 2 articles I must wrap these divs in a row div.

How can I do this with twig ?

Thanks.

EDIT :

I tried your code (NHG) like this:

```
{% for article in articles %}
    {% if loop.index % 2 == 0 %}
        <div class="row"></div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <article class="well well-sm">
            <a href="#"><img src="{{ article.image }}" alt="{{ article.title }}" class="img-thumbnail"></a>
            <h2 class="h3 text-center"><a href="#">{{ article.title }}</a></h2>
            <div class="alert alert-success well-sm">
                {{ article.content|striptags|slice(0, 235) }}...
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" href="#">{{ article.comments|length }} Comments</a>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                {% for tag in article.tags %}
                    <a class="btn btn-default">{{ tag.name }}</a>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But it doesn't work.

I want to have something like this :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**UPDATED**:

As @Maerlyn suggested:

```
{% for row in articles|batch(2) %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for article in row %}
            <div class="col-md-6">
                // your content
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

OLD way:

Use `loop.index` (doc: [The loop variable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable)), modulo (doc: [Math operators](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#math)) and `if` (doc: [`if` statement](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html#if) )

```
{% for article in articles %}
    {% if loop.index % 2 == 1 %}
        <div class="row">
    {% endif %}
    <div class="col-md-6">
        // your content
    </div>
    {% if (loop.index % 2 == 0 or loop.last) %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @foozoor I've fixed logical mistake - please check it now.

Comment: It does not work as expected, it wraps only one .col-md-6 and the other one is outside the row.

Comment: The [`batch`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html) filter may also help: `{% for row in articles|batch(2) %}{% for article in row %}`

Comment: There are two typos: `clas="row"` must be `class="row"`

Answer (score 3):

```
{% for row in articles|batch(2) %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for article in row %}
            <div class="col-md-6">
                // your content
             {% if loop.index is divisibleby(3) %}
                 </div>
             {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest :

```
<div class="row">
{% for article in articles %}
{% if (loop.index0 % 2 == 0) and not loop.first %}
</div>
<div class="row">
{% endif %}
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    // your content
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```