# How to dynamically handle bootstrap rows in for loop?

Tags: for-loop, twitter-bootstrap-3, twig

I loop through an array of tasks I want to show. Each element has bootstrap class `col-md-3`. The current behavior is to dump all them on one row.

```
<div class="row">
{% for task in taskList.taskList %}
    {% include 'dashboard/task.twig' %} // contains a div.md-3
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

There was some stacking issue, as sometimes five elements would be seen on one row with the last two elements being below each other.

So as I am using `md-3` columns, I want to now enforce that there are 4 elements each on its own row.

This is my current solution:

```
{% for task in taskList.taskList %}
    {% if loop.first %}
        <div class="row">
        {% include 'dashboard/task.twig' %} // contains a div.md-3
    {% elseif loop.index % 4 == 0 %}
        {% include 'dashboard/task.twig' %} // contains a div.md-3
        </div>
        {% if not loop.last %}
            <div class="row">
        {% endif %}
    {% elseif loop.last %}
        {% include 'dashboard/task.twig' %} // contains a div.md-3
        </div>
    {% else %}
        {% include 'dashboard/task.twig' %} // contains a div.md-3
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am not happy with the multiple includes, also the if-else-nesting level is way to deep. Is there another way on how to handle bootstrap rows in a more concise manner?

Comment: See question [How to handle twig view and bootstrap 3 rows/columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509714/how-to-handle-twig-view-and-bootstrap-3-rows-columns?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this, simplifies it a bit at any rate:

```
{% for task in taskList.taskList %}
    {% if loop.index % 4 == 0 %}
        <div class="row">
    {% endif %}

    {% include 'dashboard/task.twig' %} // contains a div.md-3

    {% if (loop.index % 4 == 0 or loop.last) %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```